# how to create realtime firebase subnodes android problems

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to create realtime firebase subnodes

note I did not put the user changed because I have been trying to add from the mainactivity code and also because everyone I built to make this addition when creating the user went wrong.
Thank you very much in advance.
any help is welcome.

Hello i'm trying to create subnodes
within user
has

```
{
   "Users": {
     "Hr1riTVGQWWsKnOsT8n7wIBO7R63": {
       "address": "asdasd",
       "email": "a@a.com",
       "fullname": "asdasd",
       "helpsms": "123456",
       "phone": "55555555555"
     }
   }
}
```

### wanted to create a node inside users called casino and inside the casino would have the subnodes of the casino inside user

### time: with default value of 200 seconds

### reward: with default value of 200

but when i try to modify my builder everything goes wrong when i click the button. can anybody help me

Button code:

```
   addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                ref.child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



                            ref.child(userUid).child("cassino").setValue(dataSnapshot);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

my user.class

```
public class User {
    public String helpsms;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    public String address;

    public User(String helpsms, String email, String phone, String address, String fullname) {
        this.helpsms = helpsms;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String fullname;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
ref.child(userUid).child("cassino").setValue(dataSnapshot);
```

into this:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("address",dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class));
ref.child("Users").child(userUid).child("cassino").setValue(map);
```

Add the `child("Users")` and then add the values